# Fedora 37/38 kernel panics during reboot after upgrade

Tags: fedora, grub2

Whenever I upgrade Fedora and it includes a new kernel, the subsequent reboot always kernel panics, saying that it can't find the root device. What's happening is that the updated version of `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` is using a device name instead of a UUID (the device name is correct):

```
menuentry 'Fedora Linux (6.2.10-300.fc38.x86_64) 38 (Thirty Eight)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.2.10-300.fc38.x86_64-advanced-9aec70be-1bb8-47e9-9be4-be979d9f7ec1' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod btrfs
    set root='hd0,gpt3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt3  9aec70be-1bb8-47e9-9be4-be979d9f7ec1
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9aec70be-1bb8-47e9-9be4-be979d9f7ec1
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 6.2.10-300.fc38.x86_64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.10-300.fc38.x86_64 root=/dev/sda3 ro  
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initramfs-6.2.10-300.fc38.x86_64.img
}
```

After resetting this to the UUID, the system boots as expected:

```
menuentry 'Fedora Linux (6.2.10-300.fc38.x86_64) 38 (Thirty Eight)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.2.10-300.fc38.x86_64-advanced-9aec70be-1bb8-47e9-9be4-be979d9f7ec1' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod btrfs
    set root='hd0,gpt3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt3  9aec70be-1bb8-47e9-9be4-be979d9f7ec1
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9aec70be-1bb8-47e9-9be4-be979d9f7ec1
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 6.2.10-300.fc38.x86_64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.10-300.fc38.x86_64 root=UUID=9aec70be-1bb8-47e9-9be4-be979d9f7ec1 ro  
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initramfs-6.2.10-300.fc38.x86_64.img
}
```

Now, if I manually run `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` before rebooting, it also created the boot entries with the UUID. Could this be related to my `/etc/default/grub` settings?

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
#GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"

GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=true
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=false
GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub2/themes/darkmatter/theme.txt"
```

How is Fedora updating grub during an upgrade?

Comment: Your setup seems to be ... broken I guess? My grub.cfg is never updated, Fedora has been using BLSCFG for at least two releases now - with this setup there's no need to update the conf file.

Comment: I don't like BLSCFG, hence I have it disabled. I want continuity between all of my systems; Fedora seems to be the only one that uses it.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - I switched back to BLSCFG. I'll see if it works again after the next kernel upgrade.

Comment: Other distros will pick it up sooner or later. It's the only sensible way of booting.